# maven - How to solve this error : "The POM for XXX is invalid"?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, jmock, transitive-dependency

I'm building a simple project with maven. I'm unable to get it to build because a transitive dependencies is missing, namely `objenesis 1.0`.

I run maven in debug mode and got this message:

```
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[WARNING] The POM for org.jmock:jmock-junit4:jar:2.6.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.jmock:jmock-junit4:2.6.0
[ERROR] Invalid packaging for parent POM org.jmock:jmock-parent:2.6.0, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ org.jmock:jmock-parent:2.6.0
...
```

When I look at jmock-parent I can't seem to find reference to neither pom or jar type.

How can I solve this issue ?

**Nota:** We use the nexus of our company for fetching dependencies.

---

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Poc</groupId>
<artifactId>Poc</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
         <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
         <version>2.6.0</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
  </project>
```

**jmock-parent-2.6.0.pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
   <artifactId>jmock-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.0</version>
   <description>POM was created by Sonatype Nexus</description>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the dependency didn't download properly.  I would try deleting the org.jmock directory from your local M2 repository and let Maven try a fresh download of that jar.

**Edit**: When you look at `M2_REPO\org\jmock\jmock-parent\2.6.0\jmock-parent-2.6.0.pom` in a text editor does it specifically say `<packaging>pom</packaging>`? You may want to make sure your dependencies in your Nexus repo are correct as well.  I just pulled the dependency from Maven Central and didn't have a problem with it.

[image: jmock-parent pom excerpt]

**Edit 2**: It's possible that Nexus will automatically create a parent pom for you like that if it can't download it from Maven Central. Is your Nexus installation configured to download dependencies from Maven Central? Did you manually `mvn deploy:deploy-file` your jmock-junit4.jar to your Nexus repo? I'm sure there's a way to force Nexus to update that pom, or you could manually deploy the proper parent pom by downloading it from maven central and then running the `mvn deploy` command listed above.

Comment: I did it but the is still present.

Comment: Interesting problem... Updated my answer

Comment: Have a look to my update in my question. It seems that our nexus got trouble for downloading the pom file.

Comment: Updated my answer... looks like maybe a nexus config issue?

Comment: I changed the repository from which the dependency was downloaded and... everything run smoothly now ! I'll report this issue to the nexus admin. Thanks @jmcmahon