# Htmleasy maven pom issues

Tags: java, jsp, maven, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to get to use Htmleasy to work in my jetty/maven 3.0.4 (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) environment. I want to use Htmleasy to produce a View that is templated using a JSP, to which I will pass arguments (using models).

I refer to htmleasy in `pom.xml` like so (https://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/wiki/UsingMaven):

```
<!-- See https://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/wiki/UsingMaven -->
<repositories>
  <repository>
<id>htmleasy</id>
<url>http://htmleasy-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

and

```
<!-- See  https://code.google.com/p/htmleasy/wiki/UsingMaven -->

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.htmleasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>htmleasy</artifactId>
  <version>0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

It appears like maven does not like the included repositories/dependencies in the pom.xml file as it complains with the following warning during compile:

`[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode.htmleasy:htmleasy:jar:0.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details`

The debug flag `-X` shows the error
`[ERROR] 'modelVersion' is missing. @`

I checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150226/maven-how-to-solve-this-error-the-pom-for-xxx-is-invalid) and I deleted my local repository for htmleasy, but now it produces the following warning:

`[WARNING] The POM for com.googlecode.htmleasy:htmleasy:jar:0.7 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
Downloading: http://htmleasy-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com/googlecode/htmleasy/htmleasy/0.7/htmleasy-0.7.jar
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, no checksums available from the repository for http://htmleasy-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/com/googlecode/htmleasy/htmleasy/0.7/htmleasy-0.7.jar`

BTW, in both cases, the compilation goes through (BUILD SUCCESS).

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? And if anyone knows of a better documentation for this, please point me to it. Also, is Htmleasy production quality? If not, can anyone point me to a facility/framework that will help me integrate JSPs with my RESTEasy JAX-RS environment?

I am wondering if this is the reason I get the runtime error while loading my JSP (`Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: com.googlecode.htmleasy.View of media type: text/html`).

Comment: Since I am seeing some activity on this post, I should note that I got tired of trying to get Htmleasy to work, and I did not find documentation that worked or people that could help me. I did email the author, and he didn't respond either. So, I ditched Htmleasy altogether, and moved to Spring MVC.

Comment: did you find the migration to Spring MVC difficult? I'm also looking for a replacement for HTMLEasy since it seems to be no longer supported.

Comment: The migration was not at all difficult. Go for it!